# How to use custom credentials while using JGit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jgit

I am using JGit in my spring-boot application for performing git operations. I need to use the `test account` for the git operations - The commit should be from `test account`

I am using below steps to commit and push a file to GitHub with JGit:

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("PAT_token_of_test_account","");

 Git git = Git.cloneRepository().
                setURI("https://github.com/user/repo.git").
                setDirectory(new File(folderName)).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).
                call();
git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
git.commit().setMessage("test commit").setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
git.push().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```

But when I execute above code in my local, it is taking my credentials and it is committing with my username. How to force JGit to use the test account PAT and use the test account for committing?

I tried to use CredentialsProvider, but it is not working

Comment: What is in your `.git/config` for the local repository and `.gitconfig` in your home directory?

Comment: Hi @stdunbar in my `.gitconfig` it is my user.name and my user.email and in `.git/config` no user related information is there and my local repository is created after cloning it.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to commit we need to set the committer details then the respectively committer value will be used for commit.

```
git.commit().setMessage("test commit").setCommitter("username","email").call();
```